# Jplayer not playing music files, mp3, ogg and m4a

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am trying to just get a simple track playing on a simplt html page with Jplayer, I have the track in mp3 and have converted it to m4a and ogg but cant get any of them to work. All paths are correct and my markup is as follows:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "/media/02 Cello Concerto _Overture_.mp3"
            });
            },
            solution:"flash,html",
            swfPath: "jplayer",
            supplied: "mp3"
        });
    });

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-44543565-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center; background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; width: 100%; height: 100%; font-family: helvetica, arial; margin: 0px;">
    <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your code, this can have various reasons:

1. JPlayer may not be able to find "jplayer.swf". Try to add the full path to it. Since you only gave it mp3, it'll use flash fallback in firefox for example.
2. Your filename "/media/02 Cello Concerto *Overture*.mp3" contains spaces which may not be correctly handled by jPlayer.
3. You should always supply mp3 and m4a to jPlayer audio players. Otherwise you may not be able to play on some platforms (e.g. ios in your case).

**Edit**

You also don't issue a play command:

```
...
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "/media/02 Cello Concerto _Overture_.mp3"
        }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        solution:"flash,html",
        swfPath: "jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3"
    });
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow jPlayer doesn't support spaces in the url even after encoding (encodeUri/encodeUriComponent). Try renaming the file and remove spaces.